# IIS 10 500 error for static bundle content

Tags: css, asp.net, iis-10

I am migrating a legacy ASP.NET application to a new environment and i'm struggling with a static file issue.

All the static bundled files throw a 500 error so none of the javascript or css works.  However, if you browse to a file directly e.g host/app_name/Content/common/daterangepicker-bs2.css the content appears but still with a 500 error.

I have turned on failed request logging and although a LOT of output is produced there are no clear errors. The last entry in the file is this:

```
<EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000029-0003-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="BytesSent">9414</Data>
  <Data Name="BytesReceived">596</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">500</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
</EventData>
```

As you can see, there is no actual error.  I'm sure this is an IIS configuration issue but I can't fine it.

Comment: There surely must be some message returned in the 500 error?

Comment: I would expect so too @Steve but I cannot find it.

Comment: Last entry won't give you any clue because it is a GENERAL_REQUEST_END op showing that request has ended. You can see is has HttpStatus 500. Try searching for 'error' strings.

Comment: I had similar problem caused by 'mimeType' entry in my config. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201406/adding-mimemap-entry-causes-500-for-other-static-content-on-iis-express